# select object using custom "data-" attribute instead of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying out tinymce and would like to submit a custom form that contains several instances of the editor. Selecting the content using a basic id is straight forward,

```
<div id="myDivInline" data-uuid="myUuid"><p>This is to be replaced by TinyMCE <br><br>CLICK ME TO LOAD TinyMCE</p></div>
var myVar = tinyMCE.get('myDivInline').getContent();
```

However I would like to select the object based on a custom `data-` attribute. Is this possible? for example, the below fails (probably due to bad syntax structure inside `.get('div[data-uuid="myUuid"]')`

```
<div id="myDivInline" data-uuid="myUuid"><p>This is to be replaced by TinyMCE <br><br>CLICK ME TO LOAD TinyMCE</p></div>
var myVar = tinyMCE.get('div[data-uuid="myUuid"]').getContent();
```

Comment: TinyMCE's [`get()`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.get.static) method only works with `id` attributes, not selectors, so what you're attempting to do is not possible. I'd suggest reading their documentation to find an alternative method

Comment: Try using [select](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.domutils/#select) for custom query selector.

Comment: @front_end_dev That's not the same. `select()` looks at the DOM *within* the editor. `get()` is intended to find the element in the outer DOM to convert to the editor.

Comment: during `init`, a promise is returned with all the editors it initialised in an array.  Keep a reference to this, and then you could do -> `editor[0].getContent()` etc.  or `editor[uid].getContent()` etc, depending on how you want to access them.

Comment: @keith, this seems also a good option. I could not find a reference in the tinymce docs to getting the `editor[uid]` for each initialised instance. is there a method for this such as `editor.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try going with something like this:

```
$("div[data-uuid='myUuid']")
```

where you simply use selector you would use in css

Comment: How can you call a TinyMCE method, `getContent()`, on a jQuery object?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I belive those are supose to be called at DOM elements, so if you put [0] after jQuery selector you get pointer to DOM element: `$("div[data-uuid='myUuid']")[0]`. or if you just simply need the inner text go with: `$("div[data-uuid='myUuid']").text()`

Comment: @LukášGiboVaic this looks like the best way. I had done this but wondered if there was a benefit to using the default `.getContent()`. Thanks for confirming we were on the right path and the quick response

Comment: @artvanderlay yes there are benefits, it gets the editor content and cleans it.